# cloud endpoints csrf protection

Tags: csrf, google-cloud-endpoints

I'd like to send an csrf protection token with every cloud endpoints request, but I don't want to have to specify this every time I call one of my services. How would I implement a sort of proxy, that inserts this token into any call my application makes?

Comment: yep, sorry, got my terminology mixed up.

Comment: Check out http://sitr.us/2011/08/26/cookies-are-bad-for-you.html to learn about this stuff and understand why an `Authorization` header is all you really need.

Comment: I'll definitely look into that, but you don't get acces to the contents of the raw http headers in protorpc, so that's not an option on google cloud endpoints.

Comment: OAuth 2.0 is super easy to set up for Endpoints APIs, so you don't need access to the raw headers, you can just use `endpoints.get_current_user()`.